# trigger each element individually on scroll with GSAP Scrolltrigger

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrolltrigger

I am working with GSAP/Scrolltrigger and I want to change the border-radius of a div on scroll (scrub). It works but somehow it resets and loops when the next element with the same trigger class enters and I can't find the solution, what am I missing?

```js
gsap.utils.toArray(".bgcolor").forEach(function(elem) {

const $section = $(".bgcolor");
  
radiusChange = gsap.fromTo($section, { borderRadius: "1rem" },{ borderRadius: "5rem" })

  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: elem,
    start: "top 75%",
    scrub: true,
    animation: radiusChange,
    markers: true,
  });
  
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;}

.spacer {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background:black;
}

.content {
  padding:100px 0;
}

.bgcolor {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom:40px;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="spacer"></section>

<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-6 bgcolor"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-2 bgcolor"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="spacer"></section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried it by coding it the following way but that also doesn't seem to work because now it doesn't trigger the startpoint and immidiatly triggers the last rem number.

```js
const borderradius = gsap.utils.toArray('.borderradius');
borderradius.forEach(radius => {

  radiusChange = gsap.fromTo(borderradius, { borderRadius: "0rem" },{ borderRadius: "5rem" })

  gsap.to(radius, { 
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: radius,
      scrub: true,
      animation: radiusChange,
    }
  })
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;}

.spacer {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background:black;
}

.content {
  padding:100px 0;
}

.borderradius {
  height: 200px;
  background:lightblue;
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="spacer"></section>

<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-2 borderradius"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-2 borderradius"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="spacer"></section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I wasn't far off, here is the solution:

```
gsap.utils.toArray(".bgcolor").forEach(function(elem) {
const $section = $(elem);
const radiusChange = gsap.fromTo($section, { borderRadius: "1rem" },{ borderRadius: "5rem" });

  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: elem,
    start: "top 75%",
    scrub: true,
    animation: radiusChange,
    markers: true,
  });
});
```